# htaccess protect and rename phpmyadmin folder

Tags: .htaccess

i protect my phpmyadmin installation with htaccess.
But now i want to rename the url www.myurl.com/phpmyadmin in www.myurl.com/othername
and send a 404 response when a user calls /phpmyadmin.

Is it possible to do that with a rewrite condition?

Thank you for helping

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^phpmyadmin does_not_exist.html  # create 404 response
RewriteRule ^othername(/.*)?$ phpmyadmin$1   # rewrite othername to phpmyadmin
```

You could also send a `410 Gone` response. Replace the first RewriteRule with this:

```
RewriteRule ^phpmyadmin - [G]
```

Comment: Does not work for me, I'm getting a 404 on `othername`. Any ideas?